# Binance bot trade quantities

Tags: python, binance

I have been following a tutorial online and have managed to get my trade bot on binance going in fact I have 3 on the go. However I know I can buy but as yet I've not hit the sell position. So I can't see that working. I've been trying to improve my code as well. I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about what I'm trying to do. The goal is obviously to try and make some kind of a profit. The thing I'm most confused about is my BUY_TRADE_QUANTITY and SELL_TRADE_QUANTITY. Surely this would be the same as TRADE_QUANTITY? If someone could help me understand how this should work or suggest any tweaks I could work on that would be awesome.

```
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/rsrusdt@kline_1m"
RSI_PERIOD = 14
RSI_OVERBOUGHT = 70
RSI_OVERSOLD = 30
TRADE_SYMBOL = 'RSRUSDT'
TRADE_QUANTITY = 432.8
BUY_QUANTITY = 20.00
SELL_QUANTITY = 20.00

closes = []
in_position = False

client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)

def order(side, quantity, symbol,order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET):
    try:
        print("sending order")
        order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type=order_type, quantity=quantity)
        print(order)
    except Exception as e:
        print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

    
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes, in_position
    
    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message['k']

    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']

    if is_candle_closed:
        print("candle closed at {}".format(close))
        closes.append(float(close))
        print("closes")
        print(closes)

        if len(closes) > RSI_PERIOD:
            np_closes = numpy.array(closes)
            rsi = talib.RSI(np_closes, RSI_PERIOD)
            print("all rsis calculated so far")
            print(rsi)
            last_rsi = rsi[-1]
            print("the current rsi is {}".format(last_rsi))

            if last_rsi > RSI_OVERBOUGHT:
                if SELL_QUANTITY < BUY_QUANTITY and in_position:
                    print("Can execute buy trade. You will loose money")
                    in_position = False
                elif SELL_QUANTITY > BUY_QUANTITY and in_position:
                    print("Overbought and profit opportunity! Sell! Sell! Sell!")
                    # put binance sell logic here
                    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_SELL, TRADE_QUANTITY, TRADE_SYMBOL)
                    if order_succeeded:
                        in_position = False
                else:
                    print("It is overbought, but we don't own any. Nothing to do.")
            
            if last_rsi < RSI_OVERSOLD:
                if in_position:
                    print("It is oversold, but you already own it, nothing to do.")
                else:
                    print("Oversold! Buy! Buy! Buy!")
                    # put binance buy order logic here
                    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_BUY, TRADE_QUANTITY, TRADE_SYMBOL)
                    if order_succeeded:
                        in_position = True

                
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: try starting from refactoring on_message first.

Comment: Not sure that was what I was after refactoring will probably come after I know the bot is working as it should and when I have my settings correct. That's kind of where I'm after the workings of it first. As mentioned in my brief I was confused and still am confused how the SELL and BUY works and what these variables should be.